# Correct way to inherit React components

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reactjs, prototype, prototype-programming

I understand that my question is a little bit biased, but I am very new in Javascript and `prototypes`, and I read about it, but I don't really understand how to apply that techniques to my practical problems. So an example would be very helpful.
So I have a `React` component, that basically looks like that:

```
var Component1 = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
        return ({
            searchable: true,
        })
    },

function1: function () {
        return ({
            somevalue
        })
    },

render: function () {

        var redText = {
            color: 'red'
        };

        var redBorder = {
            color: 'red',
            border: '1px solid red'

        };

        return (
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <a onClick={this.props.handleAddClick}>Something</a>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>Some label</label>
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
               </form> ) 
});
```

I also have `Component2` which is basically absolutely the same, but has one additional `<input/>` inside the `return` of its `render` function.

I also have `Component3`, which shares same functions, but has different `render()` function.

So how to apply inheritance here and avoid copy-paste 3 times? I just miss some practical illustration, so I'd appreciate it.

Edit1____________________________________________________
So I tried to implement Prototype inheritance as per the first answer, but it seems React doesn't see these functions: `getInitialState()` is null, initial state is null after rendering. What's wrong with this approach?

I also tried to go according to the textbook and did:

```
function MyPrototype() {};
MyPrototype.prototype.getInitialState = function () {
    return ({
        someProperty: true;
    })
};

function Component1() {};
Component1.prototype = Object.create(MyPrototype.prototype);
Component1.prototype.render = function () {
    console.log(this);
    return (<div></div>)};

var MyComponent1 = React.createClass(new Component1());
```

But when I open my browser, I get an error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: createClass(...): Class specification must implement a`render`method.`

What am I doing wrong this way?

Edit2_______________________________________________

Actually, I see that React doesn't support mixins neither prototypes. Composition should be used instead. It's explained in this article:
[Dan Abramov's article Mixins Are Dead. Long Live Composition](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.gvmtdcnhn)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In React, inheritance for components is **severely discouraged**.
React is much better suited for expressing the same relationships via composition.

Here is an example of using composition:

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Button' style={{ color: this.props.color }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class DeleteButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button color='red'>Delete</Button>
    )
  }
}
```

Note how `DeleteButton` uses the look and feel of `Button` **without inheriting**  from it. Instead, `Button` defines its configurable parts via `props`, and `DeleteButton` supplies those props. In the actual DOM, both `<Button />` and `<DeleteButton />` would render to a single DOM node—the recursive resolution happens at the `render()` time, and this is the core idea of React.

In fact, if you don’t need lifecycle hooks or local state, you may even define components as functions:

```
function Button({ color, children }) {
  return (
    <div className='Button' style={{ color }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

function DeleteButton() {
  return (
    <Button color='red'>Delete</Button>
  )
}
```

You can even mix classes with functions. This would be impossible with inheritance, but works great with composition.

As for your specific use cases:

> I also have `Component2` which is basically absolutely the same, but has one additional `<input/>` inside the return of its render function.

You can have your `Component1` accept `this.props.children` and use them in the return value of `render()` method, and have `Component2` render to `<Component1><input /></Component>`. This is very similar to what I showed above. You also don’t have to use the `children` prop—you can pass a React element in any prop, e.g. `<Component1 footer={<input />} />`, and then you can use `this.props.footer` inside `Component1`.

> I also have `Component3`, which shares same functions, but has different render() function.

If they share any other code (e.g. utilities that calculate some data), move that code outside components into a shared module, and import it from both components.

If they share any UI, extract it into yet another component, and use it from both your components.

Comment: Unbelievable, you answered my post :) I've found today your articles and got pretty much the same corollary, so sitting around fiddling with composition this night, just needed few practical examples more. Thank you for this explanation and for your work! I use Redux extensively and I am really happy with it.

Comment: Usually I do extract components extensively, so my code doesn't repeat `render` part. What I needed is actually the way to share the same code for `getInitialState` and other functions which are the same. That's what I am trying now.

Comment: What is your use case for sharing code in `getInitialState`?

Comment: Actually, I did what you said: I have some `SharedComponent`, so I pass children to it with their own functions. It works great, the code is not repeating. Along with this children I have some global flags in `redux` store state. The `SharedComponent` renders depending on those flags. It's also chosen what `onClick` handlers for some button to use based on those flags inside `redux` state. This is correct way to go, right? The code is not repeated, and I have composition here.